# Multiple subsites in a single wordpress installation

Tags: multisite

Is it possible to create multiple subsites with in a single wordpress installation?
I have to create one hospital website with subsites for all its branches.
Here is the example

http://www.thumbayhospital.com

http://www.thumbayhospital.com/dubai

Here you can view individual location-wise websections under the same root website once you go to any of the location page.

I created this by using drupal.unfortunately, the client needs it in wordpress.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 2):

As @AntonChanning said, a multisite installation in WordPress is called a [Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). You can easily create a network following the instructions in the codex. You can choose to work with subdomains or with subdirectories, like you want I guess!